# using ajax in a page loaded by ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

i have a page loaded via jquery tabs ajax, i have a form within this page that i want to show form response via ajax. response is loading from this code:

```
$('#whois').submit(function() { 
    $.ajax({
        data: $('#whois').serialize(), 
        cache:false,
        type: "POST", 
        url: $('#whois').attr('/lib/domainchecker.php'), 
        success: function(response) { 
            $('#reply').html(response); 
        }
    });
    return false;
);
```

but my form submit to parent page instead of /lib/domainchecker.php. so i see headers of my page instead of response!

any idea what makes this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is solved, no thing related to loading page via ajax but there was an error with code, i shouldn't post to  $('#whois').attr('/lib/domainchecker.php') but just '/lib/domainchecker.php'

corrected code:

```
  $('#whois').live('submit', function() { 
$.ajax({
    data: $('#whois').serialize(), 
    cache:false,
    type: "POST", 
    url: '/lib/domainchecker.php', 
    success: function(response) { 
        $('#reply').html(response); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are loading content on the page via AJAX and you need to apply events to the loaded content you need to use the [jquery live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

```
  $('#whois').live('submit', function() { 
$.ajax({
    data: $('#whois').serialize(), 
    cache:false,
    type: "POST", 
    url: $('#whois').attr('/lib/domainchecker.php'), 
    success: function(response) { 
        $('#reply').html(response); 
    }
});
```

This of course goes on the main host page rather than the loaded content page.

Comment: and no change in result, no thing changed with this note